# Not getting new line in output

Tags: c++

When i write the code below its not displaying the required output , don't know where i am wrong , below is the code which i did for my work

my try

```
int Num=1,L=1;
while(Num < 56)
    {

    for(int t=0;t<6;t++)
    {
    cout<<Num<<endl;
    Num = Num+2;
    }

    }   
return 0;
}
```

Required Output is something like this

```
 1
 3 5
 7 9 11
 13 15 17 19
```

Getting output is

```
1

3

5

7

....
```

Comment: You are printing a single number, followed by a newline. So you get a single number on each line.

Comment: "its not displaying the above output" So what *is* i displaying? And why do you think that is the case? Hint: What do you suppose that unused `line` variable would be good for?

Comment: You're supposed to write `endl` instead of `"\n"`

Comment: @WhozCraig Displaying the same numbers in straight lines

Comment: @leemes, (`endl` is (mostly) just `stream << "\n"; stream.flush();`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl). If you just want a new line, and a flush is not required, don't `endl`, just print a new line. It isn't `endl` that adds platform specific newline; it's the text mode of the stream, for `fstream`s only.

Comment: @Griwes As he wrote he doesn't see the output, I thought he meant he doesn't see any output; thus a missing flush.

Comment: @leemes, that still doesn't justify saying "use `endl` instead of `"\n"`".

Comment: Hm, when you want to see the output, you should write `endl`. Probably only the last one, but beginners shouldn't be confused so much with optimizations. Just write `endl` and you're fine. Also, `endl` is more verbose. It says "end line" and I personally find it more "high level".

Comment: @Griwes and leemes , i edit my question and try to make it more clear , sorry for inconvience and unclear question in start , hope you got my question now

Comment: @leemes I also mention it in my comment that it giving me the right output but in the staright line

Comment: You have a complete mess with `Num`, `Numb` and `Number` all being used to mean (probably) the same variable. You also show an unused variable `L`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing a new line after every number. Here's a way to write it that works:

```
int main()
{
    int number = 1;
    int lineLength = 1;
    while (number < 56)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lineLength; i++)
        {
            cout << number << " ";
            number += 2;
        }
        cout << endl;
        lineLength++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are printing a newline every time you `cout` a number. So the correct way is something like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Number=1,line=1;
    while(Number < 56)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<line;i++)
        {
            cout<<Number << ' ';
            Number = Number+2;

        }
        cout << endl;
        line++;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first, count the lines, and second: count the number index in the line:)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number = 1, line = 1, i = 1;
    while (number < 56)
    {
        cout << number << ' ';
        number += 2;
        if (i < line) ++i;
        else
        {
            i = 1;
            ++line;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Number=1,line=1,i=0;
while(Number < 56)
    for(int i=0;i<=Number;i++)
    {
    cout<<Number;
    Number+=2;
    }
    line++;
    cout<<"\n";  
return 0;
}
```